# I think this is a RCB design...but I'm not sure how to analyze it

Tags: anova, experiment-design, nested-data, blocking

Edit: Clarified by including the overall question I need help with and the experimental questions of my project.

Overall question to you (ie, what I need help with): Does this experiment sound like a Randomized Complete Block Design and if so, do you include interactions between block and fixed factors in your model (using JMP).

I ran a field experiment in 2015 and I designed it to be a RCB factorial ANOVA. The thing is, I may have made a mistake/deviated in order to save replicates.
The experiment is geared towards understanding competition in mussels. I have two species which are very similar, so much so that people mistake them for each other. However, one species is currently pushing the other one out of the river, and only one study has been done on the competition between these two when they live with each other. Instead, competition studies have only focused on individual characteristics living apart.

Experimental questions:

1. Which of my two study species is better equipped to handle exploitative competition? (who can grow better when food is taken by others around them?)
2. Do either of my study species react differently when living with conspecific neighbors than when living with the other species (does your neighbors' species impact your ability to feed/grow?)
3. Does position within a mussel bed (or in this case tube) affect your growth? (how bad is being last in the lunch line?)
4. Which of the two species is better equipped to handle interference competition? (who is more impacted by having neighbors? who takes greater advantage of having no neighbors?)

The experimental design was set up like this:

1. I had 9 cinderblocks (the blocks)
2. On each block were three tubes, each packed with a different species of mussel. (neighbor treatment, species were zebra, quagga, and empty shells - a physical control)
3. Within each tube, there were 9 positions along the length of the tube (position treatment)
4. At each position there was one of each of two species of target mussels. (species - zebra, quagga)
5. To try to understand effect of being alone or in isolation (interference competition - because mussels need room to open their shells to feed), positions 1, 5, and 9 were given fenced off free space, while positions 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 were in group chambers packed with the neighbor mussel treatments (iso treatment). I nested this within iso treatment because certain positions were unique to isolation while others were unique to being with neighbors.

I should point out that I know I didn't randomize the blocks. I did this because boaters often take or accidentally cut lines to experiments, so I wanted to be sure I got the same number of each neighbor treatment tube back at the end of the season.

I thought this experiment would be an ANOVA with the following setup: 
Neighbor vs. iso vs. species vs. position[nested in iso] with blocking as a random factor. I removed interactions between position and iso because of nesting.

My questions to you are:

1. Is it appropriate to use block even if I didn't randomize them?
2. If I use blocking, do I consider the interactions between block and the fixed factors? I've seen that RCB assumes no interaction, but I've seen other places that say I should still add them to the model
3. I use JMP for my stats, and when you include a random factor it doesn't include it in the effect tests, meaning it tells me the percentage of the variation caused by the random factor, but not a F ratio or P value, so I don't know how to report it.
4. Should I analyze those in isolation separately from those in neighbored treatments? This was suggested by a labmate who thinks it isn't interesting. My argument is that I want to know how each of my two target species responds to each of the neighboring species, regardless of isolation or neighboring (as well as which neighbor species has a greater impact on the target species). I also worry that separating them is "dishonest" if there is some interaction.

Sorry if this is all terribly convoluted. I'm happy to answer any questions and will edit this post to reflect any clarifications.

Comment: You have done a good job of relating your confusion, but not so good a job of asking a question. Just  a suggestion, even simple data collection is complicated to analyze, and is sometimes hopelessly inconclusive. You have got to organize this into questions that are less confused.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've clarified the overall questions a little bit. Does this help at all?

Comment: Not my call, but others seem to have been more satisfied with current format.